LSI raid, there is a copyback on dhs
I found an unpleasant situation. For some reason, a copyback on dhs began, I usually put dhs at 24 did. After the copybook is completed, can I transfer the disk to dns? or do I need to rebuild the raid?
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State  DG       Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                      Sp Type 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
65:24    32 Cpybck  -   1.635 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST1800MM0129               U  -  

